# Get data for the SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below scenario and looking for following result as an output can some one help me to make it possible.

```
CREATE TABLE ##RUN_ID 
(
    RUN_ID INT, 
    EMPID INT, 
    STARTDT VARCHAR(10), 
    VAL CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO ##RUN_ID (...) 
VALUES (1, 1, '1/1/2018', 'A'), (2, 1, '2/1/2018', 'A'),
       (3, 1, '12/1/2017', 'A'), (4, 1, '3/1/2018', 'A'),
       (5, 1, '2/1/2018', 'A')

SELECT * FROM ##RUN_ID
```

Output:

```
RUN_ID EMPID STARTDT   VAL
------ ----- --------- ---
3      1     12/1/2017 A
5      1      2/1/2018 A
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a homework completion service. Your instructor gave you the assignment, not us, and you're going to need to do your own work. If we do it for you, you don't learn anything. If you can't get started, ask your teacher for help; they're being paid to teach you. Good luck. (And if it's not homework, find a SQL tutorial. This is an extremely basic SELECT, which any tutorial can teach you how to do.)

Comment: Why are you using `varchar` to store dates?

Comment: What the logic to get the expected result?

Comment: Ken White …. Can you give me query if it is not complex to get the data?

Comment: Hint: Add a `WHERE` clause only matching the two `RUN_ID` you want.

Comment: This is not the actual table …. Run ID will get increase on each run and we need the older StARTDT and the one that get overwritten after each run

Comment: This is not a *do my homework* site. Perhaps you and your [classmate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50615319/62576) should work together. It appears they are further along on their assignment than you are so far. Please read my previous comment again. Ignore the *If it's not homework* sentence, as it clearly *is* homework.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you want latest run_id based on `year` if so, then you can do with `correlation` approach :

```
SELECT r.*
FROM RUN_ID r
WHERE run_id = (SELECT MAX(r1.run_id)
                FROM RUN_ID r1
                WHERE YEAR(r.STARTDT) = YEAR(r1.STARTDT)
               );
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/04fe5/4)