# Pick right Effective Dates with backdated and future dates scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Scenario 1:

```
Table as,
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#RUN_ID') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #RUN_ID

;WITH RUN_ID as ( 

SELECT 1 AS RUN_ID,1 AS EMP_ID, '1/1/2018' STARTDT, 'A' AS VALUE
UNION
SELECT 2 AS RUN_ID,1 AS EMP_ID, '2/1/2018' STARTDT, 'A' AS VALUE
UNION
SELECT 3 AS RUN_ID,1 AS EMP_ID, '12/1/2017' STARTDT, 'A' AS VALUE
UNION
SELECT 4 AS RUN_ID,1 AS EMP_ID, '3/1/2018' STARTDT, 'A' AS VALUE
UNION
SELECT 5 AS RUN_ID,1 AS EMP_ID, '2/1/2018' STARTDT, 'A' AS VALUE
    )

SELECT * INTO #RUN_ID from RUN_ID

RUN_ID  EMP_ID  STARTDT VALUE
1   1   1/1/2018    A
2   1   2/1/2018    A
3   1   12/1/2017   A
4   1   3/1/2018    A
5   1   2/1/2018    A
```

RUN_ID is every day incremental value in the table. VALUE Column can be same or different.
Need to derive the result for the STARTDT's as below:

```
RUN_ID  EMP_ID  STARTDT VALUE
3   1   12/1/2017   A
5   1   2/1/2018    A
```

Note: The last records of RUN ID 5 is over writing all other records, where StartDt of 2/1/2018 record to be in target and RUN ID 3 should be in result, as its over writing the previous RUN ID StartDT

Scenario2:

```
RUN_ID  EMP_ID  STARTDT VALUE
1   1   1/1/2018    A
2   1   11/1/2017   A
3   1   12/1/2017   A
4   1   3/1/2018    A
5   1   2/1/2018    A
```

In this case, result should be

```
RUN_ID  EMP_ID  STARTDT VALUE
2   1   11/1/2017   A
3   1   12/1/2017   A
5   1   2/1/2018    A
```

Comment: what is the logic or rules for the required result ?

Comment: Is this the same (presumably homework) as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615052/get-data-for-the-sql-query?

Comment: Good catch @stickybit

Comment: Rule is: for Scenario 1 - RUN_ID is latest run in the table. While looking at all 5 records, The Last RUN_ID , Date has to generate for sure for result. i.e. 2/1/2018 and RUN_ID 5 value.
For RUN_ID 4, Date is 3/1/2018, which is overwritten by RUN_ID 5 which has StartDT less than RUN_ID 4's StartDT. Hence that date is not there in result.
Similarly, for the prior 3 run ids, RUN_ID has StartDT less than first 2 RUNIDs, which overwrites the result. Hence with this, result to be generate is 12/1/2017 And 2/1/2018 dated records alone.

Comment: yes, same as other link. Will close one.

Answer (score 0):

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#RUN_ID') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #RUN_ID

;WITH RUN_ID as (

SELECT 1 AS RUN_ID,1 AS EMP_ID, CAST('1/1/2018' AS DATE) STARTDT, 'A' AS VALUE
UNION
SELECT 2 AS RUN_ID,1 AS EMP_ID, CAST('11/1/2017' AS DATE) STARTDT, 'A' AS VALUE
UNION
SELECT 3 AS RUN_ID,1 AS EMP_ID, CAST('12/1/2017' AS DATE) STARTDT, 'A' AS VALUE
UNION
SELECT 4 AS RUN_ID,1 AS EMP_ID, CAST('3/1/2018' AS DATE) STARTDT, 'A' AS VALUE
UNION
SELECT 5 AS RUN_ID,1 AS EMP_ID, CAST('2/1/2018' AS DATE) STARTDT, 'A' AS VALUE
    )

SELECT * INTO #RUN_ID from RUN_ID

SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT *
,LAG(STARTDT) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY RUN_ID DESC) LAG_DATE
,CASE WHEN LAG(STARTDT) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY RUN_ID DESC) IS NULL THEN 0
WHEN STARTDT < LAG(STARTDT) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY RUN_ID DESC) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END SCD_IND
 FROM (
SELECT *
, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID,STARTDT ORDER BY RUN_ID DESC) RN
 FROM #RUN_ID
 ) A
WHERE A.RN=1
) A WHERE SCD_IND=0

RUN_ID  EMP_ID  STARTDT VALUE   RN  LAG_DATE    SCD_IND
5   1   2018-02-01  A   1   NULL    0
3   1   2017-12-01  A   1   2018-03-01  0
2   1   2017-11-01  A   1   2017-12-01  0